# How can I receive data from state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to fetch data, get it to state and then modify it

```
state = {
        data: []
}
```

I have this state with an empty array, then I fetching data from API

```
constructor(){
        super();
        this.getItem();
    }

    getItem(){
        this.service
            .mergeData()
            .then((body) => {
                this.setState({
                    data: body.map(product => product),
                })
            })
    }
```

And then I am trying to use this data from state:

```
dataToFilter = this.state.data.map((e) => {
        return e;
})
```

But the problem is `dataToFilter` is empty because the state is empty.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Edit:*** OP asked the below question, so I have updated my StackSnippet to reflect this question.

> I need to use data in the state not in the render function but in the component after the componentDidMount. Am I able to do that?

If you want to load data after the component mounts, you can use the `componentDidMount` life cycle method.  You can read more on life cycle methods [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#the-component-lifecycle) and [here](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/).

Furthermore, you will need to use an `arrow function` with `getItem()` ***if you are not binding the method inside the constructor***..

[CodePen showing](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/NQvVyx) how to use a class method in the constructor via an arrow function.

[CodePen showing](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/MNvdGo) how to use a class method *without* an arrow function, using `bind`, in the constructor.

Here is how you can use `componentDidMount` to retrieve API data:

[CodePen Mirror](https://codepen.io/oze4/pen/aewwBo)

```js
class ApiFetcher extends React.Component {
  state = {
    apiData: "",
    id: 1
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.getNextFromApi();
  }

  getNextFromApi = () => {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/${this.state.id}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(json => {
        this.setState({
          id: this.state.id + 1,
          apiData: json
        }, () => {
          // After you set your state, 
          // you can use the callback that `setState` provides
          this.doSomethingWithData();
        });
      });
  }
  
  doSomethingWithData = () => {
    // Here is where you can do something with the data
    this.setState({ message: 'Check your console!' });
    console.log("I am doing something with the data!", this.state.apiData);
    // Do whatever you need to here
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>        
        {this.state.message ? <p>{this.state.message}</p> : ""}
        <hr /><br /><br />
        <h3>Just pretend this does not exist, if you do not want to display data here</h3>
        <button onClick={this.getNextFromApi}>Next Result</button>
        {this.state.apiData ? (
          <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state.apiData, null, 2)}</pre>
        ) : (
          <p>Unable to get data..</p>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <ApiFetcher />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.body);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I need to use data in the state not in the render function but in the component after the componentDidMount. Am I able to do that?

Comment: I believe I am understanding what you are asking - I have updated the snippet in my answer to reflect how you can do this.  Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Bingo. Yes. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better, you use componentwillupdate method for call dataToFilter.
Or
This code call in render method.

```
  dataToFilter = this.state.data.map((e) => {
      return e;})
```